# Trick for recompiling web api at development time

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, build

I am writing a Web API for after using in my mobile project via C#. I created an ASP.NET Web Application than at the creation pop up screen i chose Empty Template then chose Web API for "folders and core references".

Everything is ok for now. I setup the app in my local IIS. I am writing my controllers and i can call it via browser or any other appropriate Http call but there is something which makes me crazy. I have to build the Application any time I change something.

Normally when developing web sites it is not necessary to build for simple changes unlikely for Web Application projects, I know that.

But can I create my project in Web Site or is there a trick which recompile every time a change happens in project?

Comment: If there are changes in the source code, binaries should be recompiled, full stop, however, CI and CD are processes that help you to deliver changes faster, by build & release definitions, triggers and automation scripts.

Comment: Have you decoupled the front end and back end? If they're in the same project then yes, you will have to recompile everything if you make a change.

Answer (score 0):

No tricks and that's not something you want anyway.

There's a difference between client side apps and back end apps. The back end needs to compile to machine code which means the compiler needs to run first.

As opposed to that your JavaScript code loads and runs on the client side and if you make a mistake, you'll know it when you run the website.

With the compilation on the back end, you know straight away when something is wrong, you don't need to run the project, it won't even build.

If you have a project like an MVC website for example, which has both front end and back-end then yes, every time you want to run it, even if you make a front end change, the build process will still kick in, but it won't rebuild assemblies which haven't changed so the process will be quick.

If you do have back-end changes then those changed projects will need to rebuild properly to recreate the assemblies ( dll files ) your project outputs.